# Maven build war doesn't work properly on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, tomcat7, maven-jetty-plugin

I've been working on a web app that and here's me configuration before I get started telling my story.

Configuration: IntelliJ IDEA 11 + Java 7 + (Maven + Jetty 8.0.1).

When I clean and build my app on intelliJ, everything works as expected and nothing goes wrong; pages load, rendering are perfectly fine. Then I use -mvn clean package command to build my project so I'll test my app on Tomcat 7. 
However, when I deploy my application to Tomcat, some pages aren't as I saw on my maven build: renderings doesn't work properly, styling is a little bit deprecated and so on...
Even some pages doesn't load fully when I check on firebug.

I wish someone encountered a similar issue; this thing is making me crazy... If you need any logs or anything just name it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apperently, there's always nuances that you miss sometimes and browsers keep extensive data of the pages you browser. I've just cleared all of my browsers caches and now everything works perfectly!.. So if you encounter something similar, be sure to clear your browser cache.

Comment: How do you install Jetty for Intellij?